# Getting a nullpointer exception error for a function that has to return distance between two cities in Clojure

Tags: function, csv, clojure, nullpointerexception, distance

```
(defn distance [record1 record2]
  (let [R 6378.137
        dlat (Math/toRadians (- (latReturn record2) (latReturn record1)))
        dlon (Math/toRadians (- (longReturn record2) (longReturn record1)))
        lolnice (Math/toRadians (latReturn record1))
        dnice (Math/toRadians (latReturn record2))
        a (+ (* (Math/sin (/ dlat 2)) (Math/sin (/ dlat 2))) (* (Math/sin (/ dlon 2)) (Math/sin (/ 
dlon 2)) (Math/cos lolnice) (Math/cos dnice)))]
    (* R 2 (Math/asin (Math/sqrt a)))))

(distance (city "Toronto") (city "New York"))
```

record1 and record2 are rows from a csv file of cities and their attributes.

The functions latReturn and longReturn return the lats and longs respectively from these rows. When I call the distance function though I get a nullpointerexception error? I've looked at the function but can't seem to find what's causing it? Any help would be great

Comment: Hello, are you sure the latReturn and longReturn methods are working and not throwing the nullPointerException? If not, please attach them too because it is hard to tell where the problem is from the attached code. A NullPointerException is thrown when the app tries to use a null/nil value, check that the two methods dont return nil and that record2 and record1 are not nil.

Comment: If you have an exception please also add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: (defn longReturn [line]
    (def x line)
    (def y (string/split x #","))
    (def my-map { :city (y 0)
               :lat (y 1)
               :long (y 2)
               :country (y 3)
               :iso2 (y 4)
               :admin (y 5)
               :capital (y 6)
               :pop (y 7)
               :popproper (y 8)
    })
    (read-string (my-map :long))
)

Comment: Actually (city "New York") was the thing returning the null value. The function works now when I use an actual city from the CSV file. Thanks for the help!